# How to add an import widgets functionality to wordpress themes without a plugin

Tags: theme-development, import

I am trying to add one click demo install functionality to my themes. I have been able to add content and customizer options so far; but I am stuck at importing widgets.

I have been following this tutorial: [One Click demo content installation feature in WordPress theme options panel](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158443/one-click-demo-content-installation-feature-in-wordpress-theme-options-panel)

But it doesn't show how to import widgets!

I hope my question is clear.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by import widgets? Do you need to transfer the settings for widgets from some other website or what exactly?

Comment: @MilanPetrovic I want to import widget settings and content into a new fresh website. I mean I want to give my customers the option to make their the website like the theme demo with just one click. I was able to import posts content and customizer settings , the problem is I don't know how to import the widgets?

Answer (score 0):

WordPress doesn't have a way to do this on its own.

The best plugin to export widgets on one website I used, and import them into another website is [Widget Importer & Exporter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-importer-exporter/).